# Two layouts configuration in config.xml

Tags: magento

I am trying to use two layout files, one for taking data from user and saving it into database and other to display content from it.I don't know how to configure config.xml for adding two layout files in magento.

Here is my layout configurations in config.xml

```
<layout>
  <updates>
    <helloworld>
      <file>displaydata.xml</file>
    </helloworld>
    <helloworld>
      <file>helloworld.xml</file>
    </helloworld>
  </updates>
</layout>
```

Comment: you can do that with single layout file

Comment: i am new to magento and i dont know much,can you tell me a bit more so that i can get  your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your single layout file to define multiple handlers.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-layouts-and-templates-with-magento--cms-21419

In this tutorial, at last it is specified how to use our custom layout for extension.
You can add new handler like follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mymodule_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/mymodule" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/mymodule.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </mymodule_index_index>
    <!-- this is new handler -->
    <mymodule_index_test>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/mymodule" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/test.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </mymodule_index_test>
</layout>
```

And in controller you can add relevant action for this new handler